# How is the term "physiological measurement" defined?

Tags: physiology, experiment-design

Does the measurement have to be subconscious?

Can measurement such as eye-tracking be counted as physiological measurement? (I thought it is because of its relatively subconscious nature until I saw [this](https://www.slideshare.net/InsideScientific/integrating-eye-tracking-data-with-physiological-measurements).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Physiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physiology) is a very broad term that includes neuroscience:

> Physiology is the scientific study of the functions and mechanisms
>   which work within a living system.

Within the cognitive sciences, physiology typically refers to non-behavioral inputs and outputs of the nervous system (including parts of the brain), but [physiological measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychophysiology#Measures) may include behavior:

> Physiological responses also can be measured via instruments that read
>   bodily events such as heart rate change, electrodermal activity (EDA),
>   muscle tension, and cardiac output. Many indices are part of modern
>   psychophysiology, including brain waves (electroencephalography, EEG),
>   fMRI (functional magnetic resonance imaging), electrodermal activity
>   (a standardized term encompassing skin conductance response, SCR, and
>   galvanic skin response, GSR), cardiovascular measures (heart rate, HR;
>   beats per minute, BPM; heart rate variability, HRV; vasomotor
>   activity), muscle activity (electromyography, EMG), electrogastrogram
>   (EGG) changes in pupil diameter with thought and emotion
>   (pupillometry), **eye movements, recorded via the electro-oculogram
>   (EOG) and direction-of-gaze methods**, and cardiodynamics, recorded via
>   impedance cardiography.